# Contact form showing blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not sure what I did, but my contact form fields are not showing on the page. I am following railscast 219. I changed the original line `<%= form_for @message do |f| %>` to `<%= form_for Message.new do |f| %>` since I was getting undefined methods for the fields.

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for Message.new do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :content, "Message" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Send Message" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Contacts controller:

```
  def new
      @message = Message.new
    end

    def create
      @message = Message.new(params[:message])
      if @message.valid?
        # TODO send message here
        flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

Contact model:

```
   include ActiveModel::Validations
    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    extend ActiveModel::Naming

    attr_accessor :email, :content

    validates_length_of :content, :maximum => 500

    def initialize(attributes = {})
      attributes.each do |name, value|
        send("#{name}=", value)
      end
    end

    def persisted?
      false
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show your Model?

Comment: Please confirm the name of your view file.

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea Model was added

Comment: @GraemeMcLean name of the view is `new.html.erb` inside contacts folder.

Comment: Try attr_accessible instead of attr_accessor (in your model), and use the @messages variable for form for.

Comment: You've added your Contact model to the question, but your controller is creating a new instance of Message.  Could you share your Message model please.

Comment: @OscarValdezEsquea I fixed the model, and the variable should be singular.  Singular I am getting `undefined method email`. Going plural with `messages` gives a `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`

Comment: @GraemeMcLean You hit it on the head. I should have a messages model, though I was trying to avoid that and use Contact only. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are pointing to a Messages model and you only included a Contacts model. Either change the variables or create the new Messages model.